# Why text is not getting shared? Please see details

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-sharing

I have added a `share` option in my app & I want to share some plain text with it.

**The problem is that suppose I chose to share with WhatsApp. After clicking the share option, when I choose a contact to share with, nothing gets shared & I get returned back to my app.**

Here is what I've done so far:

```
LinearLayout linearLayoutShareAppContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.share_app_container);
        linearLayoutShareAppContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final Handler handler3 = new Handler();
                handler3.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, R.string.share_content);
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via..."));
                    }
                }, 200);
            }
        });
```

As I'm a beginner, I'm unable to figure out the problem here.

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: @FireSun the link you posted is completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending a resource id instead of text. Try replacing `R.string.share_content` with `getString(R.string.share_content)`.

Also, you shouldn't need to do this with a `Runnable` in a `Handler`. You can create your `Intent` and call `startActivity()` directly in `onClick()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use..

```
String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.mystring);
```

then put it as argument.